# Using IBM IDA, I want to add new columns to an existing table in a DB2 database, but I am getting permission errors when I generate the ddl script

Tags: db2, privileges, ddl

I compare the 2 schemas. (my localhost database, and my data model) then after applying the changes I want, I click the button to "generate right delta DLL"

It then makes the sql script but then gives this warning:

```
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: CONTROL ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: ALTER ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: DELETE ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: INDEX ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: INSERT ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: SELECT ON schemaname.tablename
A user cannot grant a privilege to itself: REFERENCES ON schemaname.tablename
```

If I run the script, it works fine until it gets to those lines.
How do I get permissions to run these files?

Additional info:
OS: CentOS 6
DB2 version 10.5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug in IDA – it should not be generating these GRANT statements as they are superfluous.  Your best bet is to either manually edit DDL after it's generated to remove grants to your own ID and/or open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the GRANT statements, and I now get another error on the last line when it does the INSERT INTO command to copy the data from the backup table into the new table.

Here is the error:

SQL passed with no tokens. ERRORCODE=-4462, SQLSTATE=null
 Error code: -4462
 SQL state: null

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no one else even uses these technologies. Lucky bastards. Anyway, I don't really have a solution but my workaround was to manually run the SQL commands on the DB2 database.